# Creating Dynamic MongoDB Connections in Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a Node.js project using Mongoose and MongoDB, and I have a specific use case where I need to create dynamic database connections for different branches. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- I have a main database called adminBranches, which stores information
  about all the available branches.
- When a user logs in, I want to fetch the list of branches available
  to that user.
- The user should then be able to select a branch to work with, and the
  application should establish a connection to the corresponding
  branch-specific database.
- The selected database connection should be stored in the user's
  session for the duration of their session.

I've attempted to set up a global connection, but I'm now looking for guidance on how to create these dynamic connections for each user and branch. Can anyone provide insights or code examples on how to achieve this in Node.js and Mongoose?

For now I have a connection like that:

```
// config variables
const PORT: string = config.get('PORT');
const MODE: string = config.get('MODE');
const SESSION_SECRET: string = config.get('SESSION_SECRET');
const CLIENT_DOMAIN: string = config.get('CLIENT_DOMAIN');
const ORDER_CLIENT_DOMAIN: string = config.get('ORDER_CLIENT_DOMAIN');
const AUTH_COOKIE_MAX_AGE: number = config.get('AUTH_COOKIE_MAX_AGE');
const mongoUrl: string = config.get('mongoURI');

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = initializeSocketServer(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: [CLIENT_DOMAIN, ORDER_CLIENT_DOMAIN],
    },
});

//-----------------------------Middleware Start------------------//
connectDB();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

// Object to store database connections
const dbConnections = {};

// Function to create or retrieve a database connection
async function getDbConnection(dbName) {
  if (dbConnections[dbName]) {
    // If the connection already exists, return it
    return dbConnections[dbName].db;
  }

  try {
    // If the connection doesn't exist, create a new one
    const url = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${dbName}`;
    const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    
    // Store the connection in the object
    dbConnections[dbName] = { client, db };

    return db;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error; // You may want to handle this error more gracefully in your application
  }
}

// Function to close a database connection
async function closeDbConnection(dbName) {
  if (dbConnections[dbName]) {
    const { client } = dbConnections[dbName];
    await client.close();
    delete dbConnections[dbName];
  }
}

// Example usage
async function exampleUsage(branchName='mydb') {
  const dbName = branchName;

  // Get a database connection
  const db = await getDbConnection(dbName);

  // Use the db object for database operations
  const collection = db.collection('mycollection');
  await collection.insertOne({ field: 'value' });

  // Close the database connection when done
  await closeDbConnection(dbName);
}

 const testBranchDb = 'testBranchDB'
exampleUsage(testBranchDb);
```

Create a mongo db config file and use above code to manage your db connections as per provided branch name , keep connection or close connection as per your use case